# How to increase the number of push notifications with the status "delivered"

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We send about 7 push notifications per day (news app), but only 27% of them get delivered. Could you please share some ideas how to increase the number of delivered pushes.

[image: GCM statistics]

Thank you!

Comment: You have a lot of invalid requests. Do you remove invalid tokens from your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime). All your stored messages come from devices, that are currently not available (turned off, not connected, not awake, etc.). So I guess there is really nothing you could do about them.

But for the invalid requests, you should look at the response from GCM-Server (after sending requests). It will tell you the reason for failed requests. Most of the time it will be invalidated registration tokens. [See the docs again](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#response).
You should then remove those tokens from your database and not send them any messages again.

Comment: If that helped you, please accept and or upvote. Thanks.